# How to use INTO to assign select result from query inside postgres function

Tags: postgresql

In postgres I made this function, and when it's called, it prints the `count` value, not the `c.first_name` value that I passed into variable. I don't know if this is the correct way to do this. How can I correct this?

```
declare
    mostExperienced text;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, c.first_name INTO mostExperienced 
    FROM crew_members c
    INNER JOIN aircrafts_members am ON am.crew_id = c.id 
    GROUP BY am.crew_id, c.first_name ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 1;
    RETURN mostExperienced;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two variables in that `SELECT ... INTO`, so a record would probably be a better choice

```
declare
    mostExperienced RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, c.first_name 
    INTO mostExperienced 
    FROM crew_members c
    INNER JOIN aircrafts_members am ON am.crew_id = c.id 
    GROUP BY am.crew_id, c.first_name ORDER BY count DESC 
    LIMIT 1;

    RETURN mostExperienced.first_name;
END;
```

Comment: Or just swap columns in the `select` list. Or, better, move `count(*)` directly to the `order by` clause.